# How to copy files from one disk to another location with the same folder structure?

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, copy, .net

I want to make an exact copy of some files, directories and subdirectories that are on my USB drive `I:/` and want them to be in `C:/backup` *(for example)*

My USB drive has the following structure:

*(just to know, this is an example, my drive has more files, directories and subdirectories)*

> - courses/data_structures/db.sql
> - games/pc/pc-game.exe
> - exams/exam01.doc

---

Well, I am not sure how to start with this but my first idea is to get all the `files` doing this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("I:");
```

The next step could be to make a loop and use `File.Copy` specifying the destination path:

```
string destinationPath = @"C:/backup";

foreach (string file in files)
{
  File.Copy(file, destinationPath + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file), true);
}
```

At this point everything works good but not as I wanted cause this doesn't replicate the folder structure. Also some errors happen like the following...

- The first one happens because my PC configuration shows hidden files for every folder and my USB has an `AUTORUN.INF` hidden file that is not hidden anymore and the loop tries to copy it and in the process generates this exception:

> Access to the path 'AUTORUN.INF' is denied.

- The second one happens when some paths are too long and this generates the following exception:

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

---

So, I am not sure how to achieve this and validate each posible case of error. I would like to know if there is another way to do this and how (maybe some library) or something more simple like an implemented method with the following structure:

`File.CopyDrive(driveLetter, destinationFolder)`

*(VB.NET answers will be accepted too).*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void Copy(string src, string dest)
{
    // copy all files
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(src))
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(dest, Path.GetFileName(file)));
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException)
        {
        }
        // catch any other exception that you want.
        // List of possible exceptions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx
    }

    // go recursive on directories
    foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(src))
    {

        // First create directory...
        // Instead of new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name, you can use any other way to get the dir name,
        // but not Path.GetDirectoryName, since it returns full dir name.
        string destSubDir = Path.Combine(dest, new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destSubDir);
        // and then go recursive
        Copy(dir, destSubDir);
    }
}
```

And then you can call it:

```
Copy(@"I:\", @"C:\Backup");
```

Didn't have time to test it, but i hope you get the idea...

edit: in the code above, there are no checks like Directory.Exists and such, you might add those if the directory structure of some kind exists at destination path. And if you're trying to create some kind of simple sync app, then it gets a bit harder, as you need to delete or take other action on files/folders that don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This generally starts with a recursive descent parser. Here is a good example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the overloaded `CopyDirectory` Class

```
CopyDirectory(String, String, UIOption, UICancelOption)
```

It will recurse through all of the subdirectories.

If you want a standalone application, I have written an application that copies from one selected directory to another, overwriting newer files and adding subdirectories as needed.

Just email me.